# How does paypal notify you that a user has successfully paid

Tags: paypal

If we use a paypal buy it now button, how are we notified that a user has completed their transaction?

I'm guessing there is a way other than checking our email and past transactions?

I'm language agnostic at this point, so any sample code would be a great help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal has a system called [Instant Payment Notification](https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro).

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, such as fulfilling orders, tracking customers, and providing status and other information related to a transaction.

[image]

The linked page should have all the information you need to get set up.

Comment: yes, but this solution have a downside, sometimes you simply can't have urls for that, I think an api call could be a solution